# Equating coefficients using python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, coefficients

This is actually a quite simple task to do manually, given the two equation, but nevertheless I wanted to know if its possible to equate coefficients in python (maybe using numpy or sympy/scipy?).
So the equations I have look something like this:

```
y = 1.0066*x**2-1.8908*x-0.888
U = 0.5kB*(r-r0)**2
```

Now ideally the second equation should be first multiplied out to take shape like the one above and then **kB** should be calculated via the three coefficients a (=1.0066), b(=1.8908) and c (0.888) with r0 being a constant aswell (basically giving me 3 values for kB)
So the only variables are x and r ,but I am not really interested in them

Is it possible to perform such a task? Bare in mind that I am just a beginner

Thank you

Comment: What are the 3 values for kB you are looking for?

Comment: @unutbu for this particular case? They would be just numbers in the range of 2.0xx
or did you mean something else?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the calculation you described. For the example you gave, is the answer you are looking for -- the values of `kB` found by equating coefficients -- equal to `[[2.01320000000000], [1.8908/r0], [-1.776/r0**2]]`?

Comment: @unutbu yes exactly! Now I forgot to give you values for r0, but thats just a constant. How did you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `SymPy` to represent the right-hand sides as expressions with respect to symbolic variables `x`, `r`, `r0` and `kB`:

```
x, r, r0, kB = sym.symbols('x,r,r0,kB')
y = 1.0066*x**2-1.8908*x-0.888
U = 0.5*kB*(r-r0)**2
```

Now we can convert `y` and `U` into polynomials with respect to `x` and `r`:

```
In [39]: sym.poly(y, x)
Out[39]: Poly(1.0066*x**2 - 1.8908*x - 0.888, x, domain='RR')

In [40]: sym.poly(U, r)
Out[40]: Poly(0.5*kB*r**2 - 1.0*kB*r0*r + 0.5*kB*r0**2, r, domain='RR[r0,kB]')
```

[`sym.Poly`s](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html) have a [`all_coeffs`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.polytools.Poly.all_coeffs) method which returns a list of the coefficients:

```
In [41]: sym.poly(y, x).all_coeffs()
Out[41]: [1.00660000000000, -1.89080000000000, -0.888000000000000]

In [42]: sym.poly(U, r).all_coeffs()
Out[42]: [0.5*kB, -1.0*kB*r0, 0.5*kB*r0**2]
```

We can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to pair the coefficients from the two lists:

```
In [43]: list(zip(sym.poly(y, x).all_coeffs(), sym.poly(U, r).all_coeffs()))
Out[43]: 
[(1.00660000000000, 0.5*kB),
 (-1.89080000000000, -1.0*kB*r0),
 (-0.888000000000000, 0.5*kB*r0**2)]
```

and then use `sympy.Eq` to equate the expressions, and use [`sympy.solve`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html) to solve them for `kB`. The Python construct I'm using here to generate the list is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
In [44]: [sym.solve(sym.Eq(a, b), [kB]) for a, b in zip(sym.poly(y, x).all_coeffs(), sym.poly(U, r).all_coeffs())]
Out[44]: [[2.01320000000000], [1.8908/r0], [-1.776/r0**2]]
```

Putting it all together:

```
import sympy as sym

x, r, r0, kB = sym.symbols('x,r,r0,kB')
y = 1.0066*x**2-1.8908*x-0.888
U = 0.5*kB*(r-r0)**2
result = [sym.solve(sym.Eq(a, b), [kB]) for a, b in 
          zip(sym.poly(U, r).all_coeffs(), sym.poly(y, x).all_coeffs())]
print(result)
```

prints

```
[[2.01320000000000], [1.8908/r0], [-1.776/r0**2]]
```

Comment: awesome! this works like a charm and I will surely use it for the future for more complex stuff